# Declaring on different folder (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE))

Tags: php

When all files are in the same folder this code work:

```
require_once 'doit.php';
require_once 'must.php';
require_once 'sure.php';

use Gregore\doit;

$do = new doit\must();
echo $do->now();
```

But when I put the files that call the classes in different folders like this:

```
require_once '../includes/class/doit.php';
require_once '../includes/class/must.php';
require_once '../includes/class/sure.php';

use Gregore\doit;

$do = new doit\must();
echo $do->now();
```

I get this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in XXXX

The error is coming from `use Gregore\doit;`

**What is causing this to not work properly?**

Comment: Are you certains you are requiring files from the right folder ? You could maybe post the directory layout ?

Comment: Yes i am sure that it's right folder :)

Comment: The code *as presented above* does *not* contain a syntax error. So it's Unicode whitespace or whatever, which doesn't outlive copy+pasting.

Comment: See also: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)

Comment: Try moving the `use` statement above the `require_once` statements. (it shouldn't make a difference in this case, but in general it's best practice to put your `use` statements first second only to the `namespace` declaration if you have one.

Comment: You are right :) there was a condition before: `use Gregore\doit;`, when moved before the condition code worked fine :) thank you.